# How to Deploy NodeJs Project on JBoss EAP 7.0 Application Server?

Tags: node.js, deployment

I have created a Restful web services in NodeJs using Express, Promises and Postgresql database. Now and i want to deploy this code in Production server, i am new to NodeJs and also couldn't find any relevant solutions.

As if we want to deploy java project we use to WAR file on production server like this for NodeJs how to do? Any suggestions please.??

Comment: Did you find any solution?